# Fix scrolling issue on google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On google maps V3 API, I find it **very** annoying that if you zoom out on the map using the scrollbar, the page scrolls with the map. There doesn't seem to be any way to disable scrolling with jquery. Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

If you use this snippet of jquery, it will disable page scrolling using CSS while the mouse is over the map

```
$('#map-canvas').mouseenter(function() {
  $('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'height': '100%'
  });
});

$('#map-canvas').mouseleave(function() {
  $('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'auto',
    'height': 'auto'
  });
});
```